# Planets exceed the Number Box

Tags: java, numbers, number-formatting

I'm having a issue with the code below:

```
    public class Stargazing {
      public static void main(String args[]) {

      double planets = 840000;
      double numofsun = 2.5;
      double total = 0;

      System.out.println("Galaxy #"+"\t"+"Planets");

      for(int i=1;i<12;i++){
        double siSky= planets * numofsun;
        total+=siSky;
        System.out.println(i+"\t"+total);
      }
    }
  }
```

The program is meant to calculate the number of planets within a given galaxy, but the issue seems to be once the number of planets end up in the millions and billions its starts to outputs numbers like this:

```
5       1.05E7                                                                                                      
6       1.26E7                                                                                                      
7       1.47E7                                                                                                      
8       1.68E7                                                                                                      
9       1.89E7                                                                                                      
10      2.1E7                                                                                                       
11      2.31E7
```

I do not know what I should place in place of double to achieve this.

Also to make a comma appear for example: 1,200,000,000

I'll end up putting more columns, but its imperative I get these columns right so that the numbers in the others don't show up so funky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use long numbers, not ints, and use a DecimalFormat object that uses grouping. For example,

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Foo {
   private static final String FORMAT_STRING = "0";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      DecimalFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat(FORMAT_STRING);
      myFormat.setGroupingSize(3);
      myFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);

      System.out.println(myFormat.format(10000000000000L));
   }
}
```

This will output: 10,000,000,000,000

Edit, or if you must use doubles, you could always use `System.out.printf(...)` which uses the formatting abilities of java.util.Formatter. Here you can specify the width of your numeric output, the number of decimals to include and whether or not to include group separators (with the `,` flag). For instance:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  double planets = 840000;
  double numofsun = 2.5;
  double total = 0;
  System.out.println("Galaxy #" + "\t" + "Planets");
  for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
     double siSky = planets * numofsun;
     total += siSky;
     System.out.printf("%02d: %,14.2f%n", i, total);
  }
}
```

Which returns:

The key to using printf is to use the right format specifiers.

- `%02d` means to create a numeric String from an int value, 2 chars in width with leading 0 if needed.
- `%,14.2f` means to create a numeric String from a floating point number (indicated by the `f`), that is 14 chars wide, has 2 decimal places (as indicated by `.2`) and with grouping of output as indicated by the `,` flag.
- `%n` means print a new line, equivalent to `\n` for print or println statements.

---

**Edit**
Or even better, use similar format specifiers for both column heading String and the data row Strings:

```
public class Stargazing {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      double planets = 840000;
      double numofsun = 2.5;
      double total = 0;
      System.out.printf("%8s %13s%n", "Galaxy #", "Planets");
      for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
         double siSky = planets * numofsun;
         total += siSky;
         System.out.printf("%-8s %,13.2f%n", i + ":", total);
      }
   }
}
```

This would print out:

```
Galaxy #       Planets
1:        2,100,000.00
2:        4,200,000.00
3:        6,300,000.00
4:        8,400,000.00
5:       10,500,000.00
6:       12,600,000.00
7:       14,700,000.00
8:       16,800,000.00
9:       18,900,000.00
10:      21,000,000.00
11:      23,100,000.00
```

Comment: Thank you Hovercraft Full Of Eels